# css grid 2 column, left column 1 item, right column all other grid items

Tags: html, css, sass

Considering the following html:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">5</div>
</div>
```

How does one achieve the following layout using only css:
[image: layout]

I've had a look at grid-template-areas but having the right column's items resize dynamically based on the number of items didn't seem possible. Ideally I'd like there to be a simple answer like this https://codepen.io/hc4zrr324/pen/rNOvWyr?editors=1100 but actually working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61100628/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif kinda...the absolute positioning doesn't allow for the stacked items to collectively be flush (in height) with the single item column. I'm starting to think this isn't possible without a container around the left column.

Comment: which item need to define the height? the (1) or the other items?

Comment: @TemaniAfif the items on the right

Comment: So the absolute positionning is what you need: https://jsfiddle.net/ownzturd/ .. I simply removed the min-height and changed the position of the elements